# How to run this program in Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4

I have made this python program for Windows. Please help me run for Raspberry Pi. This is a voice chat bot program to recognize commands and reply the task according to it. It runs well on windows python IDE but sadly not responding on Raspberry Pi. Please help me resolve this issue and tell me how to run this program in Raspberry 4

Error on this line:

```
engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5') voices = engine.getProperty('voices') 
# print(voices[1].id) engine.setProperty('voice', voices[0].id)
```

---

Program:

```
import pyttsx3 #pip install pyttsx3
import speech_recognition as sr #pip install speechRecognition
import datetime
import wikipedia #pip install wikipedia
import webbrowser
import os
import smtplib
import time
import pyfirmata
from pygame import mixer

try:

    board = pyfirmata.Arduino('COM5')
    led = board.get_pin('d:6:o')
except:
    print("Arduino is not connected")
x=0

def songPlayer(x):
    i =x

    music_dir = 'E:\\Songs'
    songs = os.listdir(music_dir)
    mixer.init()
    mixer.music.load(os.path.join(music_dir, songs[i]))
    mixer.music.play()


engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
# print(voices[1].id)
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[0].id)


def speak(audio):
    engine.say(audio)
    engine.runAndWait()


def wishMe():
    hour = int(datetime.datetime.now().hour)
    if hour>=0 and hour<12:
        speak("Good Morning!")

    elif hour>=12 and hour<18:
        speak("Good Afternoon!")   

    else:
        speak("Good Evening!")  

    speak("I am cham Sir. Please tell me how may I help you")       

def takeCommand():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Listening...")
        r.pause_threshold = 1
        audio = r.listen(source)

    try:
        print("Recognizing...")    
        query = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-in')
        print(f"User said: {query}\n")

    except Exception as e:
        # print(e)    
        print("Say that again please...")  
        return "None"
    return query



if __name__ == "__main__":
    wishMe()
    while True:
    # if 1:
        query = takeCommand().lower()

        if 'wikipedia' in query:
            speak('Searching Wikipedia...')
            try:

                query = query.replace("wikipedia", "")
                results = wikipedia.summary(query, sentences=2)
                speak("According to Wikipedia")
                print(results)
                speak(results)

            except:
                speak("sorry I unable to find it")

        elif 'open youtube' in query:
            webbrowser.open("youtube.com")

        elif 'open google' in query:
            webbrowser.open("google.com") 


        elif 'What is your name' in query:
            speak("I am cham sir")


        elif 'who created you' in query:
            speak("mr. logesh mohan created me")

        elif 'play music' in query:
            speak("playing Music")
            songPlayer(x)


        elif 'next song' in query:
            x+=1
            songPlayer(x)


        elif 'previous song' in query:
            x-=1
            songPlayer(x)


        elif 'stop music' in query:
            mixer.music.stop()


        elif 'the time' in query:
            strTime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")    
            speak(f"Sir, the time is {strTime}")

        elif 'light on' in query:
             led.write(1)

        elif 'light off' in query:
             led.write(0)

        elif 'make a call' in query:
            print(calling)





        elif 'go and sleep' in query:
            exit()
```

This is a program for AI Assistant

Comment: are you sure `pyfirmata.Arduino('COM5')` is correct on the pi? shouldnt it be something in `/dev/tty*`?

Comment: What errors are you seeing? It is hard to help without knowing the problem. One obvious thing - `music_dir = 'E:\\Songs'` that's not how directories in Linux are used. It would usually be something like `/home/username/Songs/`

Comment: It showing error in this line `engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
# print(voices[1].id)
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[0].id)`

Comment: @logesh This should be in your question, not buried in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Pyttsx3 code initialisation changes from windows to Linux as the voice ID will differ.

Try to tweak this snippet, this works perfectly with Linux Ubuntu:

```
import pyttsx3

engine = pyttsx3.init()

engine.setProperty('rate', 150)
engine.setProperty('volume', 0.5)
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
for voice in voices:
    engine.setProperty('voice', voice.id)
    # engine.say('The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.')
    engine.say("Hello, I am robot")
engine.runAndWait()
```

You can chose a voice ID from the available list and use the ID-constant to initialise the engine.

Since you haven't mentioned the error log, it can also be caused as you dont have espeak installed on your system

you can try this out to fix espeak error:

```
sudo apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get install espeak
```

In case the problem still persists add the error log so we can help further.